# How to turn off jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a table and the TDs have a class and based on that class I'm adding click events to it like this

```
$('#regRegionsTable').on('click', '.toggleDetail', toggleDetail);
```

I'm using `on` because the table appears, goes away, and returns, and so on, so I need to be able to add events to the table as it gets added to the DOM. In certain circumstances I need to disable the events for a specific row. I'm trying it like this, but it's not working.

```
$(row).off('click', '.toggleDetail');
```

row is the TR DOM node. So I'm trying to get all of the TDs in the row that have the `toggleDetail` class and turn off the click event binding.

Comment: why don't you change the class on the row?

Comment: That would make sense. Thanks!!

Comment: if `row` is table what you need you can simply use `$(row).off('click')`

Comment: One more thing about adding-deleting classes: if there are some styles for `toggleDetail`, then you should use two classes (one for JS handling, another one for CSS handling), not mixing logic with rendering.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example that could be useful. I add the click event on each td.  On certain circumstances (clicking on a button in my example) I disable the click event for all the td on a specific row (the first row) using `unbind()`

```js
$('#regRegionsTable td.toggleDetail').on('click', toggleDetails);

function toggleDetails(){
  console.log("click avvenuto")
}

$("button").on("click",function(){
$('#regRegionsTable tr:first-of-type td.toggleDetail').unbind('click', toggleDetails);
})


function toggleDetails(){
  console.log("click avvenuto")
}
```

```html
<table id="regRegionsTable" border="1">
<tr>
<td class="toggleDetail">1</td>
<td class="toggleDetail">2</td>
<td class="toggleDetail">3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="toggleDetail">4</td>
<td class="toggleDetail">5</td>
<td class="toggleDetail">6</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button>Remove event on a specific tr</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```